# xindy: Character #\u0438 cannot be represented in the character set CHARSET:ISO-8859-1

Tags: imakeidx, xindy

When I try to run pdflatex (via texstudio 3.0.1, version 2.15 TeX Live 2019/dev or via MikTex) with option \usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx} I get this error:

Character #\u0438 cannot be represented in the character set CHARSET:ISO-8859-1

The character is changing from time to time.
Using a command without parameter [xindy] works well but not give a desirable result.
My text is in Ukrainian, a text encoding utf8.

How this issue can be solved?

Comment: CHARSET:ISO-8859-1 is latin-1 so does not have any cyrillic characters, can you provide a complete small example, why is xindy trying to use that encoding?

Comment: Thank. Your hint allowed me to look at the problem from the other side. I realized the issue doesn't lie in encoding.

Comment: Switched to XeLaTeX. Under Windows, it still gives errors, if long directory path. If short one it works. Under Linux, all is going well.

Comment: the message is (I think) coming from xindy so I'm surprised it makes any difference which tex engine you use. But as you have not provided any example, hard to guess.

Answer (score 1):

The question is missing a complete example, so it is not fully clear what the problem is. However, it is possible that the configuration options regarding encoding are not specified correctly for the `xindy` call. The following code works in producing an index with `pdflatex` (compile with `--shell-escape` to allow `xindy` to be run automatically):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=texindy,options=-C utf8,title=Індекс]
\begin{document}
Безбарвні зелені ідеї\index{ідея} люто сплять

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Running your example helped me to locate the problem. I got another error (PARSE-NAMESTRING : syntax error in filename "D:\\\\Хемометрика\\\\Хемометрика посібник\\\\TEX\\\\zjVmGf6DPP"). A directory path contains too many characters. In the short name's directory, all works fine.

Comment: Sadly. But this approach doesn't work under Linux. A path is still too long.

Comment: @Harvester that is strange, I wonder if indeed the length of the path is the problem. Maybe you can try a path without spaces, or a path without Cyrillic characters, to isolate the issue. You could also try to run `xindy` (or in this case better `texindy`) manually from the terminal on the generated `.idx` file (so the command would be `texindy -C utf8 yourfile.idx`) to check if the problem is with `xindy` or with the interaction between `imakeidx` and `xindy`.

Comment: it seems not only. In windows under MikTex [xindy]{imakeindex} works when short directory name. In Linux, TeXLive gives the error "Character #\u0438 cannot be represented in the character set CHARSET:ISO-8859-1" in all cases when a Cyrillic term is used. If the term is in English, everything works well. Running the command from a terminal gives the same error.